# Do there exist methods to identify quadratic components in a linear model with R?

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Suppose we have an additive model of the form y=x1+x2+... with a lot of variables. Is there a routine in R to identify variables that should be considered as exhibiting a quadratic effect? I know that Box-Cox transformation allows to identify links for y, but what about x. If there are just a few variables, it's easy to test them, but what about holding a whole bunch?

Regards from Germany

Answer (score 8):

You probably don't care to know whether you need quadratic terms, but rather whether any of the effects are non-linear. While a quadratic term can pick up some of those, there are some decidedly non-quadratic effects that are not linear. There are many ways of doing that, but I like using restricted cubic splines as implemented in the `Hmisc` and `Design` packages.

For example:

```
library(Design)
x1 <- runif(200)
x2 <- runif(200)
x3 <- runif(200)
x4 <- runif(200)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(200)
f1    <- ols(y ~ rcs(x1,4) + rcs(x2,4) + rcs(x3,4) + rcs(x4,4))

> anova(f1)
                Analysis of Variance          Response: y 

 Factor          d.f. Partial SS  MS         F    P     
 x1                3   19.2033740 6.40112466 7.96 0.0001
  Nonlinear        2    5.6426655 2.82133277 3.51 0.0319
 x2                3   10.6042751 3.53475836 4.40 0.0051
  Nonlinear        2    0.5047319 0.25236593 0.31 0.7309
 x3                3    3.0844406 1.02814688 1.28 0.2829
  Nonlinear        2    0.1474818 0.07374091 0.09 0.9124
 x4                3    4.1770965 1.39236549 1.73 0.1619
  Nonlinear        2    4.1770665 2.08853325 2.60 0.0771
 TOTAL NONLINEAR   8    9.5322762 1.19153452 1.48 0.1660
 REGRESSION       12   37.1220435 3.09350362 3.85 <.0001
 ERROR           187  150.3064834 0.80377799
```

`ols` is essentially the equivalent of `lm`. Note the ANOVA table in the output: it has test for non-linearity of the effects including a global test.

Comment: +1 Agree. If you have sufficient numbers you can also investigate crossed RCS terms:  rcs(x1, 3) * rcs(x2, 3)

Comment: In your example, x1 has a nonlinear effect (low p-value), right? Then, how you could model it in order to have a good fit to the data? last, but not least, in your example, the effects are linear, why did you find out a non linear effect? misspecification problems?

Comment: @Manoel: multiple testing is the likely cause of the fake significant value. Note that the overall test of any nonlinear effect is not significant. The spline _is_ a model for the data, it is just way more flexible than a parabola.

Comment: +1 for deciphering the question and suggesting restricted cubic splines in place of simple (and questionable) quadratic effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create all the two-way interactions you can do this:

```
lm(y ~ (x1 + x2 + x3)^2, data=dat)
```

See:

```
?formula
```

Comment: I know. Sorry for my english, but this wasn't my question :)